# Octopress: Tables and Definition Lists not showing in rake preview

Tags: octopress, kramdown

Hi I dont know if this is the normal behaviour but if possible would like to preview tables and definition lists.
Using latest versions:
I am using the kramdown version of markdown.
I haven't deployed yet which means I only have 
a source but no Masters folder.

I use rake generate or rake preview commands only.
I have tried

```
| First cell|Second cell|Third cell
| First | Second | Third |

First | Second | | Fourth |

size  material      color
----  ------------  ------------
9     leather       brown
10    hemp canvas   natural
11    glass         transparent
```

and for definition lists

```
apples
  : Good for making applesauce.
oranges
  : Citrus!
tomatoes
  : There's no "e" in tomatoe.
```